# Entity Framework 6: Problema no gerenciamento de contextos

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho o objeto Agenda e o crio da seguinte forma:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();
        var treinoDAO = new TreinoDAO();
        var agendaDAO = new AgendaDAO();

        var treino1 = treinoDAO.ObterTreino(1);
        var treino2 = treinoDAO.ObterTreino(2);

        var agenda = new Agenda();
        agenda.Data = new DateTime(2017,12,11);
        agenda.Horario = "14:00";
        agenda.Observacoes = "";
        agenda.Treinos.Add(treino1);
        agenda.Treinos.Add(treino2);

        agendaDAO.Cadastrar(agenda, 2);
    }
}
```

Ao cadastrar, o EF da erro dizendo que há vários contextos gerenciado o mesmo objeto (nesse caso, o objeto treino). Isso porque utilizei outro contexto para buscar os treinos. Então tento 'desatachar' e adicionar ao contexto novamente, porém o problema persiste:

```
public class AgendaDAO
{
    private PJContext _db = new PJContext();

    public void Cadastrar(Agenda agenda, int clienteId)
    {
        agenda.ClienteId = clienteId;

        foreach (var treino in agenda.Treinos)
        {
            _db.Entry(treino).State = EntityState.Detached;
            _db.Entry(treino).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        _db.Set<Agenda>().Add(agenda);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'

Quando faço o "Detached" não adianta nada, pois acho que somente o outro contexto que o está observando pode fazer isso.
Há alguma forma de tirá-lo do contexto?

Comment: Você esta dando Dispose no seu Contexto após você consultar?

Comment: Ah, não fiz isso :|

Comment: Faça o teste se vai arrumar o problema e compartilhe com a comunidade, se arrumar eu respondo a pergunta.

Comment: Engraçado, eu busco o objeto, armazeno numa variável depois dou o disposed e retorno o mesmo, mas ele da erro falando que não da para buscar o objeto pq dei o dispose.

Comment: Esse objeto é IQueryable? Enquanto ele for IQueryable ele não vai estar na memória e você vai dar dispose antes de ele ser colocado. Faça a conversão utilizando o ToList() e veja se resolve.

Comment: Vishe, não sei muito trabalhar com IQueryable. Tentei tirar o List<Treino> da Agenda para IQueryable<Treino> e criar um método de adicionar treino e dentro desse método converter o IQueryable para List. Mas o problema é que dá erro no mapeamento fluent api, pois ele não aceita IQueryable.

Comment: Depois de buscar o objeto, desatachei ele e retornei, deu certo. Mas não sei se essa é a melhor forma a se fazer.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68810/discussion-between-gabriel-coletta-and-raphael).

Comment: O contexto fica observando suas entidades em busca de alterações. Quando você instância um novo DbContext ele desconhece essas alterações (pois elas estão em outro DbContext). Trabalhar em EF com múltiplos DbContext acaba ficando complicado. Talvez a melhor solução seja utilizar [singleton pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o dispose da conexão com o banco. Quando você não faz isso, a sua primeira consulta faz com que o Entity Framework faça o tracking desse objeto (Utilizar o `.AsNoTracking()` ajuda isso não acontecer). Depois quando você tentava adicionar ele, você estava fazendo novamente o track desse objeto, logo fazia duas vezes, isso não pode acontecer.

O problema com o IQueryable é que ele constroi uma árvore de expressões da consulta no banco, enquanto você não chamar o `.Execute()` ou fazer a conversão, ele não fez a consulta dos valores.

Você estava fazendo o dispose (ação de liberar a conexão com o banco) antes do IQueryable realmente ser executado e trazer o resultado da consulta, logo quando você tentar retornar ele, ele vai ver que a conexão com o banco foi liberada e  o erro acontecer.